# How to generate a certificate (.crt file) in iOS using swift or where to find documentation on it

Tags: ios, swift, ssl-certificate

I am working on an app where I am trying to generate a .crt file. I know what all of the necessary parameters should be (at least most). I am having trouble finding any documentation on this. Apple has this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/CertGet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH224-SW1), but it is only on managing certificates. Not on actually creating them. Where can I read more about creating them, or if anyone has done this, can you explain the process to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best you should do is to use existing tools like OpenSSL command line application...
You can wrap it in a swift application if you want to. But if it's a one time creation just use the tool

I don't remember if it's pre installed in OS X or not
[Check this out](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/openssl.1ssl.html)

[Guide to create self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

[Full guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs)

Comment: So this confirms that I cannot make it with some apple library. I will just have to embed openSSL then. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It looks like apple does not like the use of open ssl, under the 'Open SSL' section see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html

Comment: Very important link. I still think you should use OpenSSL because as Apple said it is commonly used in the community. And to solve the problem the said that the API is not stable- you can do their solution and just provide a single OpenSSL version bundled in your app. Than you're covered.

Comment: It's easier to use a library that has so many great examples out that. By the way, I used OpenSSL myself, very easy to use, and every error will give you plenty of great answers in Google or SO